# How to compose two partial orders in Sage?

Tags: sage, poset

Suppose I have two finite posets (e.g. constructed with `sage.combinat.posets.posets.FinitePoset`).

I want to calculate the binary relation which is the [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_of_relations) of the order relations of these posets.

How to do this in Sage?

(I am a Sage novice.)

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, apparently.  See [Trac 24542](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/24542) for a general future implementation of binary relations (which is what you'd likely need, since this sort of composition of posets probably usually threatens not to be a poset?).

Comment: It is **my** patch!

Comment: Haha, that is great!  I didn't even notice that.  Well, clearly you are not such a novice.  I suggest continuing the discussion on the Trac ticket - also, there is a sage-combinat Google group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sage-combinat-devel where you will get good suggestions.